# Typewriter effect in tailwind and next.js

Tags: css, next.js

I'm trying to implement this typewriter effect and it's almost exactly like how I want it, but I cant figure out how to get the printing to be done correctly. As the code is right now each word is printed on new line and kind of just falls into place when its done printing, but I want it to print each word and then continue on the next line when it reaches a little bit before the container.

heres my global.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.typewriter {
  border-right: 0px solid;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: typing 2s steps(40), cursor .4s step-end infinite alternate;
}


@keyframes cursor {
  50% {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
}


body {
  @apply bg-gray-100;
}
```

page.js

```
'use client';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'; 

export default function LandingPage() {
  const [phraseIndex, setPhraseIndex] = useState(0);
  const [fadeIn, setFadeIn] = useState(true);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setFadeIn(false);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setPhraseIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % userSearchExamples.length);
        setFadeIn(true);
      }, 500); // Change this to match the duration of the fade out animation
    }, 5000); // Change this to set the duration for each phrase

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [phraseIndex]);

  const handleLoginClick = () => {
    router.push('/login');
  };

  const handleRegisterClick = () => {
    router.push('/register');
  }; 

  const userSearchExamples = [
    "Find me an outfit for a night out",
    "What would go well with a grey hoodie?",
    "I need a dress for a wedding",
    "I need a casual outfit for a date",
    "What should I wear to a job interview?",
    "Help me find an outfit for a vacation"
  ];

  return (
    <main>
      <div className="w-full h-screen grid grid-cols-5">
        <div className="col-span-3 bg-customColor">
          <p className="text-purple-400 p-1 font-bold inline-flex gap-2 text-2xl items-center absolute left-5 top-5">
            FashionFinder
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircle} className="w-5" />
          </p>
          <div className="h-full flex items-center">
            <p className={`typewriter text-purple-400 text-4xl font-semibold text-left ml-4 mr-5 ${fadeIn ? 'fade-in' : 'fade-out'}`} key={phraseIndex}>
              {userSearchExamples[phraseIndex]}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-span-2 bg-black flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
          <p className="text-3xl font-bold text-white">
            Get started
          </p>
          <div className='flex gap-4 w-full p-6'>
            <button
              className="p-4 bg-blue-700 font-bold w-full rounded-lg shadow-xl text-white"
              onClick={handleLoginClick}>
              Login
            </button>
            <button
              className='p-4 bg-blue-700 font-bold w-full rounded-lg shadow-xl text-white'
              onClick={handleRegisterClick}>
              Register
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your css to be like this

```
.typewriter {
  text-transform: none!important;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0; /* Remove auto margin to align left */
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  animation: typing 3.5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: orange; }
}
```

Alternative you can follow these steps to create the effect using tailwind css only.

1. Edit you tailwind config to this:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      animation: {
        typewriter: 'typewriter 2s steps(11) forwards',
        caret: 'typewriter 2s steps(11) forwards, blink 1s steps(11) infinite 2s',
      },
      keyframes: {
        typewriter: {
          to: {
            left: '100%',
          },
        },
        blink: {
          '0%': {
            opacity: '0',
          },
          '0.1%': {
            opacity: '1',
          },
          '50%': {
            opacity: '1',
          },
          '50.1%': {
            opacity: '0',
          },
          '100%': {
            opacity: '0',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Then you can make the typewriter effect like this:

```
<h1 class="relative w-[max-content] font-mono 
before:absolute before:inset-0 before:animate-typewriter before:bg-white 
after:absolute after:inset-0 after:w-[0.125em] after:animate-caret after:bg-black">Hello World</h1>
```

This is a [Live Preview](https://play.tailwindcss.com/FSWpXQA9Dg)

Comment: but this doesnt fix the issue where if the sentence get too long, it will continue on to the next line, hence wrapping